# Give cloned elements a unique numerical id name each time it is cloned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, clone

I have 3 select options that are used to combine to make one value for a hidden field "episode_airdate". The problem is that the `<table tr>` they are in gets cloned, therefore the ids will get clone too, which makes getElementById useless. I tried ByName and ByClass with no luck.

```
<script>
        function datepopulate(){
    var day = document.getElementById('airdate_day').value;
    var month = document.getElementById('airdate_month').value;
    var year = document.getElementById('airdate_year').value;
   var completedate = day+'-'+month+'-'+year;
   document.getElementById('episode_airdate').value = completedate;
      alert(document.getElementById('episode_airdate').value);
   return true;
}

</script>
```

With generated numbers added it would be something like this airdate_year[1] + airdate_month[1] + airdate_day[1] = episode_airdate[1] ?

If jQuery has a better way to do this i'm opened to that idea

Comment: what does document.getElementById('episode_airdate[]') do? 'episode_airdate[]' is not a valid element id!

Comment: `"episode_airdate[]"` works for `name`s but not for `id`s.

Comment: @gwynhowell I changed "episode_airdate[]" to "episode_airdate"

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I fixed the id value; however I still face the original problem with multiple ids

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a good solution for this. You can't clone whole parts of your HTML page - ids and all - and then change it post-insert. You're supposed to fix the HTML *before* you insert the cloned bits.

Take a look at your cloning process? Maybe don't make it a generic clone, but rather a generator that can generate specific HTML, and the ids are based on dynamic data.